# Memory management in Contiki-OS

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, contiki

I am trying to create a port for Contiki-os to LPC1347, and i have a question as to how exactly is memory handled in Contiki. Protothreads are stack-less and no "real threads" are used so everything is basically on the same stack, so it is basically static memory allocation. I understand how protothreads work but when a new process is initialized, how is memory allocated for it and also, in case of an event having data, how is memory managed for event data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All required memory is statically allocated during compilation/linkage. Its done by the PROCESS Macro[1], which allocates a structure containing the necessary information [2]. As for the events, they must allocate their own memory, too[3].

It is therefore not possible to run the same thread* or schedule the same event twice.

* Actually it is, but not using the PROCESS macro.

[1] https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/5bede26b/core/sys/process.h#L301-311

[2] https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/5bede26b/core/sys/process.h#L315-326

[3] https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/5bede26b/core/sys/process.c#L62-66

Comment: Thanks again! I have one more question though, since the variables are global, for an event, they cannot get updated until the event's process is completed.

Comment: Don't see a question, but it's probably yes.

Comment: Do you know where i can find the reference manual for Contiki 2.7? I am getting errors when i try to make it with doxygen.

Comment: You can ignore those errors. It should still build fine.

Comment: It pauses and asks for input when i run `make pdf`, i get the following prompt: `(Please type a command or say \`\end')`.

Comment: Thanks! I had one more question though ( :P ), here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760101/contiki-undefined-reference-to-etimer-set).